# Starling game for iOS rejected by App Review

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flashdevelop, starling-framework

My starling game works great compiled locally and testing on my iPad.

I created the release build and sent it to apple but the game was rejected because:

> Specifically, we found your app launches to a white screen.

This error never appears when testing, I get a white screen for one seconds but
the game starts.

Whats is going on here?

Mirza

Comment: You may want to try using the XCode simulator to run your application on a few different iOS versions (particularly 6 and 7 as version 7 broke some things)

Comment: i made it on windows using flashdevelop

Comment: yes! no launch image for ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you agree that "your app launches to a white screen". Perhaps that is why it was rejected?

Add a launch image.

Answer (score 0):

A nice idea is to slap up an image similar to the default.png loadimage in standard flash when your app starts. Then when your starling stuff is loaded, remove the image and you get a seamless transition.